# Programatically Multiline not working in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uilabel, multiline

I want to set UILabel with multiline programatically in ios.Xamarin.

I have created UILabel this way and add it to my View below is the Code.

**Code :**

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();


            var label = new UILabel();
            label.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 10, secondContainer.Frame.Size.Width - 20, 20);
            label.Text = "First Label First Label First Label First Label First Label First Label";
            label.Lines = 0;
            label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
            secondContainer.AddSubview(label);
            secondContainer.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(label, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 0, 20));

            secondContainerHeight.Constant = label.Frame.Size.Height + 20;
        }
```

but my label is not taking more than one Line.

**Note :**

> this 2 property not working well
>
> ```
>  label.Lines = 0;
>  label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
> ```

I have tried search on google and SO but nothing is help me.

Any Help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the UILabel width doesn't have enough space so it needs to "grow".

Also use the `SizeToFit()` method in your UILabel, something like:

```
label.Lines = 0;
label.SizeToFit ();
label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
```

Hope this helps!